# How to fix "int' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i want to extract 'src' from 'img' tag
I have the code

```
lists = soup.find(class_="image-container image__pic js-image-pic")   
for img in lists:
       image = img.find('img')['src']
       print (image)
```

And i got this error 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What does `img.find` return?

Comment: which line do u get the error? I think `img.find('img')` is an integer and you cannot index it with `src`

Comment: lists returns: <img alt="Lightshot screenshot" class="no-click screenshot-image" crossorigin="anonymous" id="screenshot-image" image-id="e7lpy" src="http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/2867/52099098.png"/>

<div class="under-image"> <img src="https://prnt.sc/e7lpy"/> </div>

Comment: try to print the reslut of img.find('img') display it then you can index the src with simple way

Answer (score 2):

I imagine there is other useful information in the error (you should always put a full error trace), but without this I will say you are likely using `.find()` when you mean to use `.find_all()`. One will return a list, and the other will return a single item. I imagine (again, speculating since there is no trace posted) that if you ran:

```
lists = soup.find_all(class_="image-container image__pic js-image-pic")   
for img in lists:
    image = img.find('img')['src']
    print(image)
```

It would work as expected. When I have encountered this error that has been the solution for me at least

Comment: when i use find_all() i got error 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: @MA1DAN well, I can't really help too much with the information provided. I have no idea what the HTML looks like (no link provided, nor full initial stack trace). I was just proposing a likely solution based upon my experiences (to try to fill in the gaps of missing information)